# Implementing a UIView that can stretch and rotate with touches

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to implement a rectangular view that does the following. When the user drags the rectangular view from the left or right, it stretches as below:

[image]

When the user pulls up or down on the UIView, it rotates as below:

[image]

Wondering if someone can give me a clue on how to implement this. I don't believe you can do it with gesture recognizers. Does anyone know?

UPDATE: This is actually not bad to do assuming there is no rotation. You can just stretch it by the amount the user dragged left or right, or rotate it by the amount they pulled it up. However, when the view is rotated, this methodology no longer works since the points change. Any idea on how to execute this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these UIView methods. You subclass can override these methods and do what you require.

`touchesBegan:withEvent:, touchesMoved:withEvent:, touchesEnded:withEvent:, touchesCancelled:withEvent:`

- Implement these methods if you need to handle touch events directly. (For gesture-based input, use gesture recognizers.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with gesture recognizers. However, you'll need to tell iOS what to do with the view when those gestures occur.

The code that you would put in your rotation gesture recognizer action would look something like this:

```
self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(CGAffineTranformIdentity, self.rotationRecognizer.rotation);
// Where myView is an outlet to your UIView
// rotationRecognizer is an outlet to your rotation gesture recognizer
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a Github project that shows how to easily use each type of UIGesture including pinch resizing and rotation.

Checkout the Pinch, Rotate, and Simultaneous sections. I think you'll find exactly what you're looking for.

https://github.com/EmperiorEric/UIGestures